# How to prevent from manually changing the date greater than max-date for uib-datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, datepicker

I had a datepicker where I had set the max-date to today date..It is working..But the issue is can manually change the date greater than max date in the text field itself...How can we prevent this

```
fiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cpu4euoj/58/

Ex:When I click on text field ,the date picker opens and I can select date greater than today..But manually I can change the date greater than today

can someone help.Thanks.

Comment: what about add "readonly"

Comment: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php

Comment: @Osgux how could i forget this...thanks

Comment: I wasted a lot of time in typing this question :(

Comment: sometimes happends =D no problem

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like so:

[working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpu4euoj/59/)

```
   $scope.checkDate = function(AvailableDate){          
      if(AvailableDate > this.availableDateOptions.maxDate){
       $scope.AvailableDate = this.availableDateOptions.maxDate;
      }
    }
```

*HTML:* (add ng-change)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}" ng-model="AvailableDate" ng-change="checkDate(AvailableDate)" name="availabledate" is-open="availableDatePopup.opened" datepicker-options="availableDateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" ng-click="OpenAvailableDate()"
           placeholder="Available Date" />
```